# ui-bootsrap pagination: first page button is not disabled when page loads

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am displaying a list of elements inside a ng-include. 
The list of elements comes from the server using `$resource query` service.
The list is paginated with the [ui-bootstrap pagination](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination) directive. the server send the pagination informations inside the Json header (properties are named X-MyApp-…) and are intercepted by the `query` callback function.

here is the html :

```
<table ng-include src="'partials/tplList.html'" ng-init="listInit = {'type': collec.type, 'offset': 1}" ng-controller="ListCtrl" >
</table>
```

the tplList.html :

```
<tbody ng-init="loadList(listInit)"><tr ng-repeat="elm in list">
     <td>{{elm.prop1}}</td><td>{{elm.prop2}}</td><td>{{elm.prop3}}</td>
</tr></tbody>
<tfoot><tr><td colspan="4">
<span ng-show="pageCount>1">
    <pagination num-pages="pageCount" current-page="currentPage" max-size="10" on-select-page="loadList(collect(listInit, {offset: page}))">
    </pagination>
</span>
</td></tr></tfoot>
```

and the controller:

```
controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', 'List', function($scope, List) {
// collect: concatenate the objects before to send it to loadList()
    $scope.collect = function (a,b){
        var c = {};
        for (var att in a) { c[att] = a[att]; }
        for (var att in b) { c[att] = b[att]; }
        return c;
    }

    $scope.loadList = function (param) {
        $scope.list = List.query(p, function(list, response) {
            $scope.currentPage = response("X-MyApp-currentPage");
            $scope.pageCount = response("X-MyApp-pagesCount");
    console.log($scope.currentPage); // returns 1 when the page loads. 
        }); 
    }
}])
```

and the service :

```
factory('List', function($resource){
    return $resource('url/to/the/json/:type', {type:'@type'});
})
```

everything is working fine except one thing : when the page loads, the first page button ("1") inside the pagination component is not disabled like it should (and the "previous" and "first" buttons are not either). It's not disabled until i click on another page number (which is disabled correctly when selected) and then click back on the first page button.

any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a way to make it work:

removed this line from the controller :

```
 $scope.currentPage = response("X-MyApp-currentPage");
```

and added this one :

```
$scope.currentPage = 1;
```

which gives :

```
controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', 'List', function($scope, List) {
// collect: concatenate the objects before to send it to loadList()
$scope.collect = function (a,b){
    var c = {};
    for (var att in a) { c[att] = a[att]; }
    for (var att in b) { c[att] = b[att]; }
    return c;
}

$scope.currentPage = 1;

$scope.loadList = function (param) {
    $scope.list = List.query(p, function(list, response) {
        $scope.pageCount = response("X-MyApp-pagesCount");
    }); 
}
}])
```

apparently the pagination component doesn't need the `X-MyApp-currentPage` information from the server (and i'm not sure to understand why).

Answer (score 2):

This happens because ng-include creates a new scope and the model is not modified in your $parent scope.

Try the following code or create a controller that communicates with the parent one.

```
<pagination num-pages="pageCount" current-page="$parent.currentPage" max-size="10" on-select-page="loadList(collect(listInit, {offset: page}))">
    </pagination>
```